# Amazon Redshift: Queries never finish running after period idle

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-redshift, dbeaver, rjdbc

I am working on a new Amazon Redshift database that I recently started.
I am experiencing an issue where after I connect to the database, I can run queries without any issue. However, if I spend some time without running anything (like, 5 minutes), when I try running another query or command, ir never finishes.

I am using dBeaver Community 21.2.2 to interact with the connection, and it stays "Executing query" forever. The only way i can get it to work is by cancelling, disconnecting from the redshift, connecting again and then it executes correctly. Until I stop using for some minutes, and then it's happens all over again.

I tought this was a dBeaver issue, as we have a Meabase connected to this same cluster without any issues. But today, I tried manipulating this cluster with R using RJDBC, and the same thing happens: I can run queries, until I stop, and then when I try running something else it never stops, until I disconnect and connect again.

I'm sorry if I wasn't able to explain it clearly, I tried searching for simmilar issues but couldn't.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the queries in question are not even being launched on the database.  You can check this by reviewing svl_statementtext to see if the query is even being seen.  Put a unique comment in the query to help determine if it is actually the query in question.

Since I've seen similar behavior before I'll write up a possible way this can happen.  In this case the queries were not being seen by the database or the connection to the database was being dropped mid execution.  The cause is network switches and their configurations.

Typical network connections are fairly quick - you ask for a web page and it is given to you.  Connection is complete.  When you click on a link a new connection is established and also end quickly.  These network actions are atomic from a network connection point of view.  However, database connections are different.  One connection is made and many back and forth transmissions of data happen while the connection is open.  No problem and with the right set of network configurations these connections can be open and idle for days.

The problem come in when the operators of the network equipment decide that connections that have no data flowing are "stale" after some fixed amount of time.  They do this so that the network equipment can "forget" about these connections and focus on "active" connections.  ISPs drop idle connections a lot so that they can handle the load of traffic and connections that flow through their equipment.  This doesn't cause any issues for web pages and APIs but database connections get clobbered.

When this happens is look exactly like what you describe.  Both sides (client and database) think that the connection is still active but the network equipment has dropped the connection. Nothing gets through but no notification is sent either party.  You will likely see corresponding open sessions on the Redshift side for these dropped connections and the database is just waiting for the client to give a command on each of them.  An administrator will need to go through and close (terminate) these sessions for them to go away.

Now the thing that doesn't align with experience is the speed at which these connections are being marked as "stale".  In my case my ISP was closing connections that were idle for more than 30 min.  You seem to be timing out much faster than this.  In some cases corporate firewalls will be configured with short idle connection timeouts for routes out of the private network to the internet.  So there are cases where the timeouts can be short.  The networks at AWS do not have these timeouts so if your connections are completely within AWS then this isn't your answer.

To address this there are a few ways to go.  The easy way is to set up a tunnel into AWS with "keep alive" packets sent every 30 sec or so.  You will need an ec2 instance at AWS so it isn't cost free.  Ssh tunneling is the usual tool for this and there are write-ups online for setting it up.

The hard way (but likely most correct way) is to work with network experts to understand when the timeout is happening and why.  If the timeout cannot be changed then it may be possible to configure a different network topology for your use case.  Network peering or VPN could address.

In some cases you may be able to not have jdbc or odbc connections at all.  You see these protocols are valid but they are old and most networking doesn't work this way anymore which is why they suffer from these issues.  Redshift Data API let's you issue SQL to redshift in a single package and check on completion later on.  These API calls are each independent connections so there is no possibility of "timing out" between them.  The downside is this process is not interactive and therefore not supported by workbenches.

So does this match what you have going on?